# Query and extract NFT metadata from a cardano-node instance (without db-sync)

Tags: cardano-node, nft

Is there a way to query NFTs and extract NFT metadata from a cardano-node instance without using db-sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the transactional metadata are not part of the ledger state.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Then, is there a way to scan the ledger directly? Are any of the `db-*` binaries in the tarball able to this? I need something that doesn't require 40GB of RAM, so db-sync is not an option. And it also needs to be able to run independently, without external services. My last resort would be Carp.

Comment: Sadly, I do not think that information is stored anywhere by the cardano-node. Cardano-db-sync or tools like Blockfrost actually has to reply all the blocks to extract it. Try maybe looking at Kupo.

Comment: I didn't know Kupo, looks great. That could be a useful tool. In the meantime, I've been considering other approaches to make it work with db-sync and even Blockfrost. Thanks again!